# CountUp.js Update from previous number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, counter

I'm working on a project using NextJs and [CountUp.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup).
I want to be able to update the count from the previous number instead of 0.

Is this possible?

```
const [targetNumber, setTargetNumber] = useState(100)

<CountUp
 end={ targetNumber }
 duration={ 1 } 
/>
```

Comment: Just use the attribute start?

Comment: The output of the start somehow add to the target like: 20100
as in 20 is the start value. 
This happens for like 100ms